# Can't get rid of empty space between columns

Tags: python

[image]

I'm building a small addon that will grow into something more serious as I grow accustomed to Blender and make small workflow tweaks. I'm trying to set up some basic addon preferences that I can expand on later.

Under "Pie Menus" you will notice that the separation between the buttons is noticeable, and I don't know what to do to get rid of it. The very last two lines of code are the relevant ones here.

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    row = col.row()
    box = col.box()
    split = box.split()


    b1 = split.box()
    b1.label(text="Tools")
    col = b1.column(align=True)

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Direct mode switching.")

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_subd", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Toggle subdivision modifier.")

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_smartx", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Context sensitive delete.")


    b2 = split.box()
    b2.label(text="Keymaps")
    col = b2.column(align=True)

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Temporary.")

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Temporary.")

    b1.separator()
    b3 = b1.row()
    b3.label(text="Pie Menus")
    col = b3.column(align=True)

    row = b1.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Temporary.")

    row = b1.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Temporary.")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    col = layout.column(align=True)
    row = col.row()
    box = col.box()
    split = box.split()


    b1 = split.box()
    b1.label(text="Tools")
    col = b1.column(align=True)

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Direct mode switching.")

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_subd", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Toggle subdivision modifier.")

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_smartx", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Context sensitive delete.")

    b1.label(text="Pie Menus")
    col = b1.column(align=True)

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Temporary.")

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Temporary.")


    b2 = split.box()
    b2.label(text="Keymaps")
    col = b2.column(align=True)

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Temporary.")

    row = col.split(factor=0.25, align=True)
    row.prop(self, "activate_modes", toggle=True)
    row.label(text="Temporary.")
```

Comment: can you add some explanation? just posting code and a picture rarely make for good answers.